# Deep learning techniques for concept similarity?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, similar-documents

Given a corpus of product descriptions (say, vacuum cleaners), I'm looking for a way to group the documents that are all of the same type (where a type can be `cordless vacuums`, `shampooer`, `carpet cleaner`, `industrial vacuum`, etc.).

The approach I'm exploring is to use NER. I'm labeling a set of these documents with tags such as (`KIND, BRAND, MODEL`). The theory is that I'd then run new documents through the model, and the tokens corresponding to those tags would be extracted. I would then construct a feature vector for each document comprised of a boolean value for each of the tags. From there, a simple dot product would show all documents related to some base document (as in, these documents are all similar to this one document).

## Question

What are other general approaches that might be a good fit for this task?

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of existing NLP models already fulfilling this task.

For instance, the bert-base-nli-mean-tokens:
[image]

This model is too general, you will want to use a more adapted one, or build your own model based on an existing one like Bert.

Here is a complete list of models for sentence similarity:
https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=sentence-similarity&sort=downloads

Roberta, Mini-LM, MPnet are generally good options.

However, some of them could require more compute power than other solutions, but with a good GPU, it would be fast enough.